# Any way to update bios for Asus X101H without Windows?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, asus, bios

I have tried everything and no matter what the EZFLASH that comes with the netbook is not working for reading my USBs, whether FAT16, or FAT32.

In Windows, Asus has their update tool which updates the bios easily, but is there any way for me to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to update the BIOS with a DOS bootdisk that I created following the advice on this webpage : [Make DOS Bootable USB Stick](http://www.howtogeek.com/136987/how-to-create-a-bootable-dos-usb-drive//)

Once I did that, I just ran the DOS bios update utility I got from the ASUS support site with the ROM for the latest BIOS version, and....success!

Comment: Updated link...

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [ASUS bios update site](http://support.asus.com/download/options.aspx?SLanguage=en&type=1) you are asked for your motherboard model and after making your choice, the next option is selecting the OS. Linux is present there, with instructions.

As a general guide line, you should always try to search the manufacturer's site, because the default software that comes with IT products is usually for Windows.

Comment: That's not very helpful.  I followed the instructions, and their EZFLASH is not working.  Also, the machine in question is a netbook, so not your typical motherboard. AND if you check the list of OSs for this netbook on that link you gave, Linux is not present; just DOS and Windows.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to update your bios on a netbook? Any major security fixes?

Comment: Updates the embedded controller firmware.

Answer (score 0):

From within the BIOS, Select ADVANCED, Start Easy Flash